# Group by name and range mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an `areas` table like so:

`name | lat | lng`

There are many duplicate areas. `lat` and `lng` are `double` types

`atown | 80.66 | 40.1
atown | 80.51 | 40.53
atown | 81.0 | 41.0
atown | 10.0 | 20.0
btown | 70.0 | 30.0`

Currently I am doing this:

`` SELECT * FROM `areas` GROUP BY `name`, `lat`, `lng` ``

But what I want to do is this is group further based on a range of the values of `lat` and `lng`

`+/- 2` is acceptable and they can be grouped as one area:

So I should get the following result:

`atown | 80.66 | 40.1
atown | 10.0 | 20.0
btown | 70.0 | 30.0`

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use distinct and floor function.  If you want to group by 2, you'll need to floor the number and subtract floor%2 value from the floor value.

```
mysql> select distinct
->   name,
->   floor(lat) - floor(lat)%2 lat,
->   floor(lng) - floor(lng)%2 lng
-> from areas
-> ;
+-------+------+------+
| name  | lat  | lng  |
+-------+------+------+
| atown |   80 |   40 |
| atown |   10 |   20 |
| btown |   70 |   30 |
+-------+------+------+
```

Comment: I think you are close, but I don't want any of my data rounded. I just wanted it grouped by the name and the range. I have updated my question so its a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`+/- 2` means step by 4, so you could devide `lat` or `lng` by 4 as group values.

```
SELECT
    name,
    floor(lat/4),
    floor(lng/4),
    lat,               --or max(lat) or min(lat)
    lng                --or max(lng) or min(lng)
FROM 
    areas 
GROUP BY 
    name, 
    floor(lat/4), 
    floor(lng/4)
```